# Socket.io не работает

Tags: jquery, socket.io, php, websocket, сокет

Есть функция:

```
$('#button').click(function(){var val=$('#area').val();socket.emit('message',{val:val});});
```

Есть socket:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://site.com');
socket.on('message',function(data){send(data.val);});
```

И есть функция:

```
function send(val){$('#place').append(val);}
```

Все необходимые js-файлы подключены, но ничего не работает. Вопрос: что должно быть на site.com, что всё это работало?

Comment: какой нить вебсокет сервер, если php, то например phpdaemon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А где серверная часть?
Все, что вы привели это только front-end, но ведь надо еще и back-end :)

Как минимум у вас на сервере должен быть Node.js сервер + модуль socket.io и собственно сам скрипт приложения:

server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(1234);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('message', function(obj) {
         // какие-то действия
         socket.emit('message', obj);
    }
}
```

Его так же надо будет запустить: `node server.js` и перезапускать при каждом изменении, чтобы они вступили в силу

Складывается впечатление, что вы не понимаете, как back-end и front-end должны взаимодействовать. Разберем ваш код:

Этот кусок кода обрабатывает клик по кнопке и обращается на сервере к событиюу `message`:

```
$('#button').click(function(){var val=$('#area').val();socket.emit('message',{val:val});});
```

Тут в первой строчке вы пытаетесь подключиться к серверу и установить сокет соединение, а на второй - вы создаете обработчик сообщения `message` от сервера, куда единственным параметром придет data:

```
// Обязательно укажите номер порта
var socket = io.connect('http://site.com:1234');
socket.on('message',function(data){send(data.val);});
```

А это, функция, которая выполнится когда сервер пришлет сообщение `message` (в контексте вашего кода):

```
function send(val){$('#place').append(val);}
```

Исходя из всего этого, очевидно, что у вас нету серверной части, которая как раз-таки обрабатывала бы событие `message` и слала сообщение `message` (в будущем не повторяйте названия событий и сообщений, дабы не путаться). Выше я привел код, который будет создавать сокет сервер и вешать его на порт 1234. Далее идет описание события `message`, к которому вы будете обращаться с клиента, отсылая объект `{val:val}` в качестве параметра:

```
$('#button').click(function(){var val=$('#area').val();socket.emit('message',{val:val});});
```